# Encrypt the data using Silex framework

Tags: php, ssl, encryption, https, silex

I am using [Silex framework](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) for web application. I would like to encrypt the returning data from server to client/server.

Does any Silex Built-in Service related to encrypt the data such as SSL, HTTPS etc.? I had to take a look at the Silex documentation but cannot find anything.

Answer (score 3):

You can add some dependencies by composer, but if I were you, I will use apache2 to handle https and only require it in routing or .htaccess

Comment: Using your web server's HTTPS is the way to go. Simple, tested and alredy there for you.

Answer (score 2):

No, Silex doesn't include an out-of-the-box cryptography library. If you need application layer cryptography, read on. Otherwise, just use HTTPS.

Library recommendations:

1. [Libsodium](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/00-intro.md#installing-libsodium) - The hardest option to install (not by much), but the most performant and most secure solution.
2. [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) - Pretty straightforward encryption/decryption API
3. [zendframework/zend-crypt](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-crypt)

The latter two can be installed by typing `composer.phar require [library name here]` into your shell.